# Awk to update file based on match and condition in another

Tags: awk

The below `awk` will produce the `tab-delimeted file1` with the difference between `$3-$2` calulated for each line and printed in `$6`. Before the `awk` is executed only 5 fields exist.

What I am having trouble with updated each `$2` value in `file2` with the `$7` value of `file1` if the `$1` value of `file2` matches the `$5` of `file1` and `$6` in `file1` is not `intron`. If the value of `$5` is `intron` then then the value of `$7` in `file1` is zero. So for example line 1 in `file1` is `intron` so that is equvilant to zero or skipped (those lines are not needed in the calculation).

It is possible that a `$1` value in `file2` may not exist in `file1` and in this case the value of `$2` in `file2` is zero. Line3 in`file2` is an example and is set to zero because it does not exist in `file1`. Thank you:).

**Awk w/ output**

```
awk '
  FNR==NR{                 # process same line
     b[$4]=$3-$2;
     next  # process next line
}
{
 a[$5]+=($3-$2)
}
{
  split($1, b, " "); print b[0], a[b[0]]
}' OFS="\t" file1 file2
```

**Output**

```
-2135
-2135
-2222
-2351
-2351
-2414
```

**File1** `tab-delimited`

```
chr5    86667863    86667879    RASA1   intron  16
chr5    86669977    86669995    RASA1   splicing    18
chr5    86670703    86670805    RASA1   exon    102
chr5    86679453    86679547    RASA1   intron  94
chr5    86679571    86679673    RASA1   exon    102
chr19   15088950    15088961    NOTCH2  intron  50
chr19   15288950    15288961    NOTCH3  intron  11
chr19   15308240    15308275    NOTCH3  exon    35
```

**File2** `space delimited`

```
RASA1 2135
NOTCH2 0
GIMAP8 87
NOTCH3 129
FOXF2 0
PRB3 63
```

**Desired out** `after file2 is updated`

```
RASA1 222  `(102+102+18)`
NOTCH2 0
GIMAP8 0
NOTCH3 35  `(35)`
FOXF2 0
PRB3 0
```

Maybe adding a `|` after the first `awk` with:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$7; next } { if(a[$5]){$1=a[$5] }; print }'
```

To update `file2`

Comment: Instead of making the index of the array `FNR` make it `$4` and increment the value stored in the array at that index by the result of your `$3-$2` calcuation. Like `a[$5]+=($3-$2)` Then when processing the second file you can just pull the item from the array at the index that matches the first string in `$1` like `{split($1, b, " "); print b[0], a[b[0]]` (pardon if that syntax isn't 100%, but that should get in the ballpark.

Comment: I made the edits and don't think I follow, but included the output in the original post. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. It will provide you sequence of output in same order of Input_file's order.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if(!b[$1]++){
     c[++count]=$1
  }
  a[$1]
  next
}
($4 in a) && $5!="intron"{
  a[$4]+=$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i],a[c[i]]?a[c[i]]:0
  }
}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Since your Input_file1 is NOT TAB delimited as per your claim, so in case it is then edit `Input_file2  Input_file1`  ----->  `Input_file2  FS="\t" Input_file1`. To get output as TAB delimited either append above code's output to `| column -t` command or set `OFS="\t"` near to `FS="\t"` too.

Output will be as follows.

```
RASA1 222
NOTCH2 0
GIMAP8 0
NOTCH3 35
FOXF2 0
PRB3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood it correctly, this should do what you expect

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR && $5!="intron" {a[$4]+=$3-$2; next}
       {$2=($1 in a)?a[$1]:0}1' file1 file2 > file2.updated
```

Comment: IMHO  karafka sir, IMHO, I think OP mentioned it wrongly as per shown samples field from Input_file1 is 4th please.

Comment: Thank you both very much :).